# Random Destribution of arbitrary numbers of items

Tags: php, random, distribution, normal-distribution

I need a PHP function that randomly distributes an arbitrary number of darts over an arbitrary number of dartboards. It has to return the number of dartboards that have 0 darts in them, the amount of boards with 1 dart, 2 darts etc.

I have to be able to run this within a few milliseconds with millions of darts and dartboards, but an approximation is good enough. I already have a function that can give me normally distributed random values so a solution that gives the average result can be worked with.

```
//Example result with 1000 darts and 500 dartboards
Array
(
    [0] => 62
    [1] => 128
    [2] => 152
    [3] => 96
    [4] => 40
    [5] => 14
    [6] => 6
    [7] => 2
)
```

I've made a function that generates example values by procedurally distributing each dart randomly. This is for example purposes only. The production version of the function will have to use normal distribution to create results in a scalable way.

**Do not tell me how to optimize this example, its for demonstration purposes only:**

```
<?php
function distribute($items, $targets) {
    $result = array();
    $values = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$items; $i++) {
        @$values[ mt_rand(0,$targets) ] ++;
    }
    for($i=0;$i<$targets;$i++) {
        @$result[ (int) $values[$i] ] ++;
    }
    ksort($result);
    return $result;
}

$microtime = microtime(true);

echo '<pre>';

print_r( distribute(100000, 50000) );

print_r(microtime(true) - $microtime);
```

Comment: So, if you already have a function and don't want to optimize it, what's your question?

Comment: I want a function that approximates the result by using normal distribution because then it won't matter if its 1 dart or a billion.

Comment: So your actual question is how to generate normals or a close approximation quickly in php?

Comment: No, i can already create normals, what i need is a way to distribute darts randomly over dartboards with normals instead of procedural iteration.

Comment: @DanielEisenhardt That's still not at all clear.  Are you looking for locations of the darts on a given dartboard, or allocation of darts to the dartboards. If the latter, why would you think the distribution of darts across dartboards (a discrete process) would be modeled as a normal (a continuous distribution)?  [By the way, if you want the person you're responding to to see your response, tag their name with an @ as I did at the front of this.  You automatically see responses to your question, but we don't.]

Comment: @pjs It doesnt matter where the dartboard is hit. 
The X number of darts all hit a random dartboard and the Y number of dartboards can contain endless amounts of darts. The only data i want is the amount of dartboards with 0,1,2,etc. darts in them.
[Thanks for the tip on tagging people.]

Comment: Still not seeing **why** you want normality. The normal distribution gives continuous values in the range -infty to +infty, and there's a discrete set of dartboards which most people would index with a bounded set of positive integers. What do you want the mapping of ranges to integers to be? It could be anything. You haven't clearly communicated what you have in mind.

Comment: @pjs It would appear not. Darts and dartboards is just a model, perhaps its better to use cups and beads where each bead gets put in a random cup. 
My end goal is to distribute them randomly and get an array of the result. (How many have 0, how many have 1 etc.)

Comment: Then you need to choose a discrete distribution with support for the number of targets/cups/bins ([Here are some possibilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#With_finite_support)). Store counts in an array which has the number of targets as its size, initialized to all zeroes. Then generate values from that distribution and use each generated value as the index of the array element to increment.